# call other function in toaster onShown event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-toastr

I have below code to for toaster

```
    toastr.success("<br /><br /><button type='button' id='confirmationRevertYes' class='btn clear'>Yes</button>",'delete item?',
      {
          closeButton: false,
          allowHtml: true,
          onShown: function (toast) {
              $("#confirmationRevertYes").click(function(){
                hidepanel(); // not working
                this.hidepanel(); // not working
              });
            }
      });
```

I have one function outside

```
hidepanel(){
}
```

When trying to call inside toaster onShown method it throws error

> hidepanel does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

How can this work?

Thanks

Comment: What I think that happen is you are using some third party component. What will happen if you use a third party component is that `this` will be used inside that component. So to solve this you can put this `let me = this` above the toastr and then `me.hidepanel()`

Comment: Thanks, your idea worked

Comment: You're welcome :) Wasn't sure about the third party thing but I know this solution will work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a function call `hidepanel`, use the `=>` expression

```
toastr.success("<br /><br /><button type='button' id='confirmationRevertYes' class='btn clear'>Yes</button>",'delete item?',
  {
      closeButton: false,
      allowHtml: true,
      onShown: (toast) => {
          $("#confirmationRevertYes").click(() =>{ 
            this.hidepanel();  
          });
        }
  });
```

Comment: it is not showing error on compile time, but when clicking but throws error _this.hidepanel is not a function

Comment: you need to define the `hidepanel` function

Comment: function is there, if it is not there it would be throwing at compile time also

Comment: one more note. its typescript file so its defined like hidepanle() {} .. only no function keyword is there

Comment: Typescript file

Comment: do you need to use the jquery code in here. try to call the function outside of the jquery parts

Comment: Could you please help me writting this

Comment: ahh, right of course. you need to store the this into a variable so that state will not get change.